# No such filter: 'drawtext'

Tags: video, ffmpeg

My main objective is to collect user inputs and convert it to a video with black background, then the input text will be moving from left to right while the video is playing with audio in the background.

Currently I was suggested to use "drawtext" but i have not find it working.

My command:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSerif-Bold.ttf:textfile=text.txt:reload=1:y=h-line_h-10:x=(W/tw)*n" textover7.mpg -report
ffmpeg version git-2017-12-28-be4dfbf Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/ffmpeg --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/ffmpeg/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/ffmpeg/lib --bindir=/usr/local/bin --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libfdk_aac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libtheora --enable-filter=drawtext
  libavutil      56.  7.100 / 56.  7.100
  libavcodec     58.  9.100 / 58.  9.100
  libavformat    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
  libavdevice    58.  0.100 / 58.  0.100
  libavfilter     7.  8.100 /  7.  8.100
  libswscale      5.  0.101 /  5.  0.101
  libswresample   3.  0.101 /  3.  0.101
  libpostproc    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2014-01-19T03:12:30.000000Z
  Duration: 00:07:15.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 201 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und), 8, 1/30: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360, 103 kb/s, 15 fps, 15 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und), 1, 1/44100: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 96 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-01-19T03:12:31.000000Z
      handler_name    : IsoMedia File Produced by Google, 5-11-2011
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> mpeg1video (native))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> mp2 (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x466e4c0] No such filter: 'drawtext'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
Conversion failed!
```

Comment: Thank You LordNeckbeard, But it does not display any error message, and beside how can i make it to display error in my php script, Remember i am running  this on PHP not Windows command line..What i think might be my problem is that it may be that i don't know the correct syntax to use for the command may be there are some points where i suppose to use double OR single quotes.. I will be more than Happy to get the solusion here thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not a PHP user, so I am not sure what you need to do in that to get the output from the ffmpeg command, but you can add the `-report` option to your ffmpeg command and it will output a very verbose log file in the working directory (assuming your ffmpeg command is even being executed).

Comment: Okay Thank you, i can see you good with ffmpeg. My main Objective in this project is to create a website that will let my users Create videos with  the original article they write and a voice over the video. the video will have a background and the written article will be moving from right to left and an audio will be playing it. I was thought ffmpeg can handle this things that is why i go for it. Please with your experience with ffmpeg can i get this done?

Comment: Okay can you brief me the ffmpeg syntax for this?. Thanks

Comment: All The Script that i have been running, they all output video files that has 0kb size, it wont play.. Please help me with this issue This is some of my scripts   echo shell_exec('ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -vf drawtext="enable=gte(t,3):fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSerif-Bold.ttf:textfile=text.txt:reload=1:y=h-line_h-10:x=(W/tw)*n" textover5.mpg');

Comment: As I mentioned previously add the `-report` option. Provide a link to the resulting log file.

Comment: The -report is not working this is how i used it echo shell_exec('ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -vf drawtext="fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSerif-Bold.ttf:textfile=text.txt:reload=1:y=h-line_h-10:x=(W/tw)*n" textover7.mpg -report');

Comment: This is the link http://videoenews.it/v_preview.php

Comment: Hello LordNeckbeard, Thank you for your help.. I atlast got the Report as a log file on my root directory.. This is the code i run echo shell_exec("ffmpeg -f test.mp4 -vf drawtext='fontsize=64:fontcolor=white@0.8:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.75:boxborderw=16:fontfile=OCRA.ttf:text='my_video':x=(w-tw)/2:y=th' textover09.mpg -report");     And This is the the report i got

Comment: ffmpeg started on 2017-12-29 at 16:43:24
Report written to "ffmpeg-20171229-164324.log"
Command line:
ffmpeg -f test.mp4 -vf "drawtext=fontsize=64:fontcolor=white@0.8:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.75:boxborderw=16:fontfile=OCRA.ttf:text=my_video:x=(w-tw)/2:y=th" textover09.mpg -report
ffmpeg version git-2017-12-28-be4dfbf Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers

Comment: built with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/ffmpeg --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/ffmpeg/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/ffmpeg/lib --bindir=/usr/local/bin --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libfdk_aac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libtheora --enable-filter=drawtext
  libavutil      56.  7.100 / 56.  7.100
  libavcodec     58.  9.100 / 58.  9.100
  libavformat    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
  libavdevice    58.  0.100 / 58.  0.100
  libavfilter     7.  8.100 /  7.  8.100

Comment: libswscale      5.  0.101 /  5.  0.101
  libswresample   3.  0.101 /  3.  0.101
  libpostproc    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-f' ... matched as option 'f' (force format) with argument 'test.mp4'.
Reading option '-vf' ... matched as option 'vf' (set video filters) with argument 'drawtext=fontsize=64:fontcolor=white@0.8:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.75:boxborderw=16:fontfile=OCRA.ttf:text=my_video:x=(w-tw)/2:y=th'.
Reading option 'textover09.mpg' ... matched as output url.
Reading option '-report' ...

Comment: matched as option 'report' (generate a report) with argument '1'.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option report (generate a report) with argument 1.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: output url textover09.mpg.
Applying option f (force format) with argument test.mp4.
Applying option vf (set video filters) with argument

Comment: drawtext=fontsize=64:fontcolor=white@0.8:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.75:boxborderw=16:fontfile=OCRA.ttf:text=my_video:x=(w-tw)/2:y=th.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an output file: textover09.mpg.
[NULL @ 0x4671e80] Requested output format 'test.mp4' is not a suitable output format
textover09.mpg: Invalid argument   Soryy I had to split this log. Please help me review and brief me what am doing wrong.. Am not too good in ffmpeg.. Thanks in andvance..

Comment: Instead of trying to cram it all into comments you should [edit] your question to include the new information: it will also be much easier to read. Once you do that then I'll look at it. Then you can delete all of these extra comments. You should try to avoid using trailing options (these are options that are declared after the last output file) because generally `ffmpeg` may ignore them.

Comment: Why video ? You can try to combine html5 canvas (can do animation) and audio

Comment: I Have posted the report

Comment: I am Getting No Such Filters all through "No such filter: 'drawtext'
Error reinitializing filters!"

Comment: Hello LordNeckbeard.. Am still waiting for your help, Thank you.. I keek getting the same error that says "No such filter: 'drawtext'
Error reinitializing filters!"  I Really need to solve this badly... Thanks A lot

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `ffmpeg` does not support the [drawtext filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext). It is missing the configure option `--enable-libfreetype` which is required for this filter.

Download a build that has support included:

- [Windows](https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/)
- [Linux](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) (or [compile](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide))
- [macOS](https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/) (or use `brew install ffmpeg --with-freetype`)

Comment: Thank you very much sir, i completed the compilation by follow the instruction on https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos Nw i want to execute the new ffmpeg in my script as you said, how can i do that.. Thanks very much

Comment: @Femzy Did you try your script using your new ffmpeg?

Comment: No i have not tried it i want to try it but i dont know if i should use  the same command i used for the previous one

Comment: I installed the package to my public_html folder, i named the folder ffmpeg_sources. so now how can i use it instead of the one i am using before

Comment: @Femzy Provide the full path to the binary `echo shell_exec('/path/to/ffmpeg ...`

Comment: This is my path from the public_html folder.. /ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg  inside the ffmpeg folder there are some folders and files.. I Point it this way but it does'nt work

Comment: This is one of my command  but it won't work  echo shell_exec('ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg -i test.mp4 textover07.mp3 -report');

Comment: @Femzy Just saying "it won't work" is not enough information to provide much help. Do you get any errors? Is `ffmpeg` actually being executed in the script? What does the log from `ffmpeg` show? Does the PHP error log show anything?

Comment: As per what i see the script is not running.. if i use shell_exec('ffmpeg -i test.mp4 textover07.mp3 -report'); which is the one installed on the server by the server administrator it is running and produced the error log file, but if i tried to use the one i installed by my self which is the one in the site folder like this  shell_exec('ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg -i test.mp4 textover07.mp3 -report'); it won't run the code.

Comment: @Femzy Your path is probably incorrect, but I am just guessing because there is no information to make any other assumption. Try using the full path such as `shell_exec('/home/femzy/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg -i ...`. If that fails then copy the new ffmpeg binary into `/usr/local/bin` and then try `shell_exec('ffmpeg ...`.

Comment: Thank you very Much sir, I call the Server Administrator to install the libfreetext for me.. Thanks so much.. Now Remain one thing that seems difficult to me, I thought it would be easy until i come to discover i don't got it right. I want to use an image as background for the drawtext filters. I.e I want to use image as background of the video  echo shell_exec('ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=color=black -vf drawtext="textfile=text.txt:expansion=normal:fontfile=FreeSerif.otf: y=h-line_h-20:x=-100*t: fontcolor=white: fontsize=50" -t '.$words_count.' textover09.mp4 -report'); this is my code

Comment: @Femzy I was going to recommend asking a new question since we already addressed the original issue here, but I see [you already did](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48139025/1109017).

Comment: @Femzy Mulvya will provide an updated solution if you provide the requested information.

Comment: As of today, the `drawtext` filter also needs `--enable-libharfbuzz`

Answer (score 8):

The error with `drawtext` happens when your ffmpeg is compiled without libfreetype.

solution for mac os:

```
# If ffmpeg is already installed, you need to uninstall it.
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies ffmpeg

# you may very well want to specify other options
brew install ffmpeg --with-freetype
```

Comment: After uninstalling and running `brew install ffmpeg --with-freetype` I get this `Error: invalid option: --with-freetype`

Answer (score 0):

I also have this issue while ffmpeg was compiling via
--enable-libfreetype
--enable-filter=drawtext
flags.
Installing libfreetype6-dev solved my problem.

Comment: No need for `--enable-filter=drawtext` unless you manually disabled filters.