# I want to use image as a background of a drawtext video using ffmpeg

Tags: php, ffmpeg

Currently i am able to create video with ffmpeg using the drawtext filters to draw text on a black background Now Remain one thing that seems difficult to me, I thought it would be easy until i come to discover i don't got it right. I want to use an image as background for the drawtext filters. I.e I want to use image as background of the video instead of using the background color or video background. Please someone should take me through on this this is my code `

```js
echo shell_exec('ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=color=black -vf drawtext="textfile=text.txt:expansion=normal:fontfile=FreeSerif.otf: y=h-line_h-20:x=-100*t: fontcolor=white: fontsize=50" -t '.$words_count.' textover09.mp4 -report'); `
```

```js
ffmpeg started on 2018-01-07 at 22:53:03
Report written to "ffmpeg-20180107-225303.log"
Command line:
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i elena.jpg -vf "drawtext=textfile=text.txt:expansion=normal:fontfile=FreeSerif.otf: y=h-line_h-20:x=-100*t: fontcolor=white: fontsize=50" -t 46.2 textover09.mp4 -report
ffmpeg version git-2017-12-28-be4dfbf Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/ffmpeg --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/ffmpeg/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/ffmpeg/lib --bindir=/usr/local/bin --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libfdk_aac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libtheora --enable-filter=drawtext --enable-libfreetype
  libavutil      56.  7.100 / 56.  7.100
  libavcodec     58.  9.100 / 58.  9.100
  libavformat    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
  libavdevice    58.  0.100 / 58.  0.100
  libavfilter     7.  8.100 /  7.  8.100
  libswscale      5.  0.101 /  5.  0.101
  libswresample   3.  0.101 /  3.  0.101
  libpostproc    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-loop' ... matched as AVOption 'loop' with argument '1'.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input url with argument 'elena.jpg'.
Reading option '-vf' ... matched as option 'vf' (set video filters) with argument 'drawtext=textfile=text.txt:expansion=normal:fontfile=FreeSerif.otf: y=h-line_h-20:x=-100*t: fontcolor=white: fontsize=50'.
Reading option '-t' ... matched as option 't' (record or transcode "duration" seconds of audio/video) with argument '46.2'.
Reading option 'textover09.mp4' ... matched as output url.
Reading option '-report' ... matched as option 'report' (generate a report) with argument '1'.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option report (generate a report) with argument 1.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input url elena.jpg.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: elena.jpg.
[NULL @ 0x2c1fe80] Opening 'elena.jpg' for reading
[file @ 0x2c207c0] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[image2 @ 0x2c1fe80] Format image2 probed with size=2048 and score=50
[image2 @ 0x2c1fe80] Before avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 0 bytes read:32768 seeks:0 nb_streams:1
[image2 @ 0x2c1fe80] Opening 'elena.jpg' for reading
[AVIOContext @ 0x2c21f80] Statistics: 3871771 bytes read, 0 seeks
[mjpeg @ 0x2c21940] marker=d8 avail_size_in_buf=3871769
[mjpeg @ 0x2c21940] marker parser used 0 bytes (0 bits)
[mjpeg @ 0x2c21940] marker=e0 avail_size_in_buf=3871767
[mjpeg @ 0x2c21940] marker parser used 16 bytes (128 bits)
[mjpeg @ 0x2c21940] marker=e2 avail_size_in_buf=3871749
[mjpeg @ 0x2c21940] marker parser used 3160 bytes (25280 bits)
[mjpeg @ 0x2c21940] marker=db avail_size_in_buf=3868587
[mjpeg @ 0x2c21940] index=0
[mjpeg @ 0x2c21940] qscale[0]: 2
[mjpeg @ 0x2c21940] index=1
[mjpeg @ 0x2c21940] qscale[1]: 2
[mjpeg @ 0x2c21940] marker parser used 132 bytes (1056 bits)
[mjpeg @ 0x2c21940] marker=c0 avail_size_in_buf=3868453
[mjpeg @ 0x2c21940] Changing bps from 0 to 8
[mjpeg @ 0x2c21940] sof0: picture: 5616x3744
[mjpeg @ 0x2c21940] component 0 2:2 id: 0 quant:0
[mjpeg @ 0x2c21940] component 1 1:1 id: 1 quant:1
[mjpeg @ 0x2c21940] component 2 1:1 id: 2 quant:1
[mjpeg @ 0x2c21940] pix fmt id 22111100
[mjpeg @ 0x2c21940] marker parser used 17 bytes (136 bits)
[mjpeg @ 0x2c21940] marker=c4 avail_size_in_buf=3868434
[mjpeg @ 0x2c21940] marker parser used 0 bytes (0 bits)
[mjpeg @ 0x2c21940] escaping removed 6222 bytes
[mjpeg @ 0x2c21940] marker=da avail_size_in_buf=3868014
[mjpeg @ 0x2c21940] marker parser used 3861792 bytes (30894336 bits)
[mjpeg @ 0x2c21940] marker=d9 avail_size_in_buf=0
[mjpeg @ 0x2c22540] marker parser used 132 bytes (1056 bits)
[mjpeg @ 0x2c22540] marker=c0 avail_size_in_buf=3868453
[mjpeg @ 0x2c22540] sof0: picture: 5616x3744
[mjpeg @ 0x2c22540] component 0 2:2 id: 0 quant:0
[mjpeg @ 0x2c22540] component 1 1:1 id: 1 quant:1
[libx264 @ 0x2c24c40] i16 v,h,dc,p: 40% 53%  4%  3%
[libx264 @ 0x2c24c40] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 11% 10% 27%  7%  9%  8%  8%  9% 11%
[libx264 @ 0x2c24c40] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 29% 12% 11%  6%  9% 11%  7%  9%  6%
[libx264 @ 0x2c24c40] i8c dc,h,v,p: 53% 17% 21%  8%
[libx264 @ 0x2c24c40] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x2c24c40] ref P L0: 56.3%  9.9% 21.1% 12.8%
[libx264 @ 0x2c24c40] ref B L0: 74.5% 22.4%  3.1%
[libx264 @ 0x2c24c40] ref B L1: 98.3%  1.7%
[libx264 @ 0x2c24c40] kb/s:4673.55
[AVIOContext @ 0x2c28ac0] Statistics: 32768 bytes read, 0 seeks
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image -vf scale=-2:1080,drawtext="textfile=text.txt:expansion=normal:fontfile=FreeSerif.otf: y=h-line_h-20:x=-100*t: fontcolor=white: fontsize=50" -pix_fmt yuv420p -t '.$words_count.' -movflags +faststart textover09.mp4
```

Comment: Yea Thank you,  But it does not seems this will work because i tried to run the code and it takes eternal to load the page. The Output file was also currupted

Comment: Share full log. Add -report and run.

Comment: The Log file is too much but i will share it on the question above. Thanks

Comment: Hello Mulvya I was trying to upload the Log file but it is too huge and exceeded the limit. So I decided to create a page for the log file, this is the link http://videoenews.it/error_log.html this is the link to the video it generated http://videoenews.it/textover09.mp4

Comment: Okay Should i copy the path of the log? I will do now,

Comment: Okay I added few line of the  log file, But is there  a way i can attach the file so you can see the entire log?

Comment: That's the problem, your image is too big. For browser playback, stick to HD or lower. Try edited command.

Comment: Hello @Mulvya I used different picture with lower size 90kb size it is not working still. i am thinking if it is need to add frame filters.

Comment: Big refers to resolution not filesize. How are you testing playback?

Comment: I AM Using html video tag to play the video. I also download the video to my computer to play it but wont play.. This is a link to the video http://videoenews.it/textover09.mp4

Comment: @Mulvya Thank you Very Much Man I Use your updated code and it works! Great Thanks

Comment: Hello I have a problem with the command, when i tried to use a text file that has  plenty of words like more than 300 words, it generate the video but also the rest of my code did not executed, i wanted to save the path of the generated video to the database after it is created and then move to the next page but the server stop after it execute the command and not run the rest of the code

Comment: Hi @Mulvya How can i make the text start from the center when the video play? Currently it start from the left side and people dont see the first words before it goes. I want the text to start from either the center of the video or the right while moving from right to left.