# Error: No such filter: '"movie', what's the isssue?

Tags: ruby, ffmpeg, carrierwave

I am using the code to add watermarks to videos on upload for carrierwave-video:

```
process encode_video: [:mp4, resolution: "640x480", watermark: {
    path: "app/assets/images/logo-nike.jpg",
    position: :bottom_right,
    pixels_from_edge: 10
  }]
```

When i use this code, i get error:

(in short)

```
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x55c8909bf180] No such filter: '"movie'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
Conversion failed!
):
```

my ffmpeg version is 4.1.1

Is there something missing from ffmpeg i need to install? I have looked around and found no issues with others using this code (most posts are years old though)

I found this: [No such filter: 'drawtext'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48006872/no-such-filter-drawtext)

but isn't the same thing?

Comment: Need to see full ffmpeg log

Comment: Look at the log it says no such filter '"movie' -> there is a " more. What is your definition of filters?